# Generic stream and abstract data types

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

Here is a strawman program which illustrates the issue I am having

```
trait RequestBuilder {
  type Out

  def complete(p: Promise[Out]): Unit
}

def makeRequest(in: RequestBuilder): Source[(RequestBuilder, Promise[in.Out]), Future[in.Out]] = {
  val p = Promise[in.Out]

  Source.single(in -> p).mapMaterializedValue(_ => p.future)
}

val sink = MergeHub.source[(RequestBuilder, Promise[???])].to(Sink.foreach {
  case (r, p) => r.complete(p)
}).run()

sink.runWith(makeRequest(new RequestBuilder {
  type Out = Int

  def complete(p: Promise[Out]): Unit = p.success(1)
}))
```

The issue is, how do I type the `Promise[???]`  in the sink? I have been able to work around this by making the Promise a part of the RequestBuilder trait itself, but this seems like a code smell to me

Answer (score 0):

You can make a type alias for the tuple:

```
type BuilderWithPromise[B <: RequestBuilder] = (B, Promise[B#Out])
```

Or a case class:

```
case class BuilderWithPromise[B <: RequestBuilder)(
   builder: B, 
   promise: Promise[B#Out]
)
```

either way should work

Comment: This doesn't actually work, as you still have a type parameter. If you don't provide it, it will be inferred as `Nothing`. Since `Sink` are not covariant, this will prevent you from wiring anything up

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. Can you show your code, and the error you are getting?

Comment: There's a number of issues above. One is that it is using type projection, which doesn't work in this case because I need the path dependent type. The other is that both the type alias and the case class still have a parametric type that needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: For example, this doesn't compile because you haven't provided a type for `B`

`trait RequestBuilder {
  type Out

  def complete(p: Promise[Out]): Unit
}

type BuilderWithPromise[B <: RequestBuilder] = (B, Promise[B#Out])

val sink = Sink.foreach[BuilderWithPromise] { _ => }`